# python regular expression - split by dict value

Tags: python, regex, python-re

This is my data :

```
data= 'JUN 2023 02 20 INFO : data1 = data2 data3 = data4 {"app":[{"key":"app1","value":"100"},{"key":"app2","value":"200"},{"key":"app3","value":"300"}]}'
```

Based on pattern i written like this : `print(re.findall(r'(?:\w+ :)(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*=|$)', text))` . After running this code, I am getting empty list. I tried multiple pattern and there is no expected result.

My expected result is

```
[ 'data1' = 'data2',
  'data3' = 'data4'
  'app1' = '100',
  'app2' = '200',
  'app3' = '300',
]
```

Comment: First, your expected result doesn't seem reasonable. It's not syntactically valid. Second, can you modify the source of the data? If yes, then you should do that in order to use a more suitable logging format instead of trying to parse this with regex.

Comment: Atleast can we get only  app values [app1:100,app2:200,app3:300]

Answer (score 1):

I see that your string contains Json(?), so you can use `re` + `json` to parse it. E.g.:

```py
import re
import json

data = 'JUN 2023 02 20 INFO : data1 = data2 data3 = data4 {"app":[{"key":"app1","value":"100"},{"key":"app2","value":"200"},{"key":"app3","value":"300"}]}'

json_data = re.search(r"\{.*\}", data).group(0)
json_data = json.loads(json_data)

for k, v in json_data.items():
    for d in v:
        print(k, list(d.values()))
```

Prints:

```
app ['app1', '100']
app ['app2', '200']
app ['app3', '300']
```

---

The rest of the data can be parsed with:

```py
for k, v in re.findall(r'(\S+) = (\S+)', data):
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
data1 data2
data3 data4
```

Answer (score 1):

You may solve it using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with two regular expressions:

```py
>>> import re
>>> data = 'JUN 2023 02 20 INFO : data1 = data2 data3 = data4 {"app":[{"key":"app1","value":"100"},{"key":"app2","value":"200"},{"key":"app3","value":"300"}]}'
>>> re.findall(r"([^ ]+?) *= *([^ ]+)", data) + \
... re.findall(r"\"key\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\s*,\s*\"value\"\s*\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"", data)
[('data1', 'data2'), ('data3', 'data4'), ('app1', '100'), ('app2', '200'), ('app3', '300')]
```

Where

- [`([^ ]+?) *= *([^ ]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZMjXmN/1) is searching for `data1 = data2` etc.
- [`\"key\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\s*,\s*\"value\"\s*\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"`](https://regex101.com/r/6iQyDR/1) is searching for `"key":"app1","value":"100"` etc.